# compress base64 encoded string data into decode format

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

Hi im decoding the base64 string data and saving into the database like url format with time stamp so i need to compress the decoded data and my compression like if the coming data is less than 100kb then no need to compress otherwise compress the data into 50% off.

```
try

{

String FileItemRefPath = propsFPCConfig.getProperty("fileCreationReferencePath");

String imageURLReferncePath = propsFPCConfig.getProperty("imageURLReferncePath");

File f = new File(FileItemRefPath+"/"+"productimages"+"/"+donorId);

String strException = "Actual File "+f.getName();



        if(!f.exists())

        {

            if (!f.mkdirs())

            {
                System.out.println("direction creation failed");

                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            boolean isdirCreationStatus = f.mkdirs();
        }   

String strDateTobeAppended = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());

        String fileName = strImageName+strDateTobeAppended;

        savedFile = new File(f.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+fileName);


        strException=strException+" savedFile "+savedFile.getName();

        Base64 decoder = new Base64();

        byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(strImageBase64);

        if( (decodedBytes != null) && (decodedBytes.length != 0) )
        {
        System.out.println("Decoded bytes length:"+decodedBytes.length);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(savedFile);

        System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes) + "\n") ; 

        int x=0;
        {
            fos.write(decodedBytes, 0, decodedBytes.length);
        }

        fos.flush();

        }

        if(fos != null)
        {
            fos.close();

        System.out.println("file output stream"+savedFile.getName());

            return savedFile.getName();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
       try 
       {
           if( fos!= null)
           {
               fos.close();
           }
           else
           {
               savedFile = null;
           }
       } 
       catch (IOException e) 
       {

        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    return savedFile.getName();
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here. You can't really determine upfront how much any given octet stream can be compressed. If you want to compress data you can always use the LZMA algorithm. There is a pure java implementation of it somewhere. Google it. :)

Comment: sorry boss,here im getting base64 string data so it is >100 kb so i want to compress the data

Comment: Then why are you base64 ecoding the data? That adds a 33% overhead. If you compress this, the result will no longer be base64 encoded, and you're basically back to square one. What are you trying to acomplish exactly?

Comment: we are developing IOS apps so they are sending base64 encoded data that is the size may be below 100kb or above 100 kb so i need to compress if the data is above 100 kb

Comment: means i want to compress decoded data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is probably not going to be compressing it in Java. For that you can simply use something like [the Deflater class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html). On iOS however it might be a little more complicated, as I'm not sure what kind of zlib-like tools you have available in iOS.